# Codeigniter Ajax request With mysql Like query encoding string into characters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I have a problem on querying mysql with like query. I am posting a string variable to php and when I echo it as post variable it show me the correct string value but when I insert it in like query it converts the string to a character.

Consider an example I have a query

I am posting $term = 'Felix'

```
SELECT name, category FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR phone 
LIKE '%{$term}%' OR customerId LIKE '%{$term}%'
```

when I post term string as felix then it converts the fe to a character.So when i echo this query it show me this reuslt.

```
SELECT name, category FROM customers WHERE name LIKE 'şlix%' OR phone LIKE 
'şlix%' OR customerId LIKE 'şlix%'
```

What is the solution to get the like query without encoded character. Note : I have not found any solution here that is why I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and you forgot to specify the customerId after the SELECT :)
`SELECT name, category, customerId FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%$lix%' OR phone LIKE 
'$lix%' OR customerId LIKE '$lix%'`